# JQuery submit a file using AJAX where the file is not in a Form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, rest

I am creating a modal that can be used in multiple places in my application to upload files, as a result I am not using a `<form>` because this may be used within an existing form that I don't want to submit.

**Please Note:** this `<input type=file>` is **not** in an html `<form>`. I tried to post this question, but someone marked it as a duplicate and deleted it, and the 'duplicate' answers were all examples where it used a form. please do not mark this question as a duplicate if the examples use a form.

**html**

```
<input type="file" id="CustomerInvoices-${ogoneRef}" name="uploadFileNameForCustomerInvoices">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#CustomerInvoices-'+ogoneRef).change(function (e) {
    clickSubmitUploadFiles(e, ogoneRef);
});
```

I have the following JavaScript function.

```
function clickSubmitUploadFiles(event, ogoneRef) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    ;[...files].forEach(function (file) {
        let urlString = 'http://localhost:8085/papertrail/upload-document/'+userName+'/'+ogoneRef;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlString,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username+":"+password)
            },
            data: file,
            error : function (result) {
                console.log('error', result);
                },
            success : function (result) {
                console.log('success', result)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Error**

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
>     at o (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:7939)
>     at gn (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:8398)
>     at x.param (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:8180)
>     at Function.ajax (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:12615)
>     at powWowDashboard.do:18456:15
>
> jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation
>     at o (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:7939)
>     at gn (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:8398)
>     at x.param (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:8180)
>     at Function.ajax (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:12615)
>     at powWowDashboard.do:18456:15
> ```

**Problem**

So I think the problem is with the `data` I am trying to upload is not in the correct format.

I get the data as follows:

```
let files = event.target.files;
```

and then set it in the ajax request:

```
            data: file,
```

**Question**

How should I set the `data` for the uploaded file in the request?

Comment: Would you please _read_ the answers in a duplicate, instead of asking [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75554419/jquery-javascript-upload-file-using-ajax) immediately again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FormData` to send the files, even if it's not a part of any form. No need to make multiple ajax requests in a loop.

```
const formData = new FormData();
const files = event.target.files;

for (const file of files) {
  // Attach files
  formData.append('files[]', file);
}

...

$.ajax({
  ...
  data: formData
})
```

If you're using a PHP backend, the values are available in `$_FILES`